# Finding the ratio of numbers of ways of selecting at least one defective disc to number of ways of selecting no defectives

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

4 out of 18 discs are defective , if 3 discs are selected determine the ratio of the number of ways of selecting at least 1 defective disc to the number of ways of selecting no defective discs at all.

Please help i am only able to get 765 : 91

The answer is 113 : 91

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of ways of selecting no defective discs is $C(14,3) = 364$.

The number of ways of selecting any three discs is $C(18,3) = 816$.

So the number of ways of selecting at least one defective disc is $816-364 = 452$ (using the idea of a complement) and so the requested ratio is $452:364 = 113:91$.

Note that the phrase "at least one" means "not none" and this is an indication to count a complement.

Answer (score 0):

The number of ways to select no defective disc at all is 18 choose 3. Selecting at least one defective disc is the complementary case of selecting no defective disc.